# How do I uninstall NodeSource NSolid from my computer?

Tags: nsolid

I installed NodeSource's NSolid on my computer and it took over my node binary. How do I uninstall it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

N|Solid replace node binary to ensure that all your apps are getting the additional features of N|Solid. The best way to return to Node.js again is reinstalling it.

N|Solid is shipped with a specific npm version that guarantee total harmony on the ecosystem. Reinstalling Node.js also replace the npm version avoiding issues about version miss matching.

Also you should remove manually the `nsolid` binary. You can get the installed path running `which nsolid`

Answer (score 1):

NSolid provide an uninstall script. On a Mac, simply run:

```
sudo /usr/local/nsolid/uninstall
```